# Artificial sun Sculpture

Tags: sun, cooling

I am designing a dynamic sculpture of the solar system, about 6,500 feet long from the sun to Neptune. At this scale the sun will be 24 inches in diameter, Earth a quarter of an inch. Every hour the sun will rise out of a flaming cauldron. The sun will be heated to 4000° kelvin. Tantalum hafnium chloride? Two questions:

1. Assuming a Washington DC setting at 75°F, in 50 minutes what color will this artificial Sun be?
2. When it first comes out of the ground how close can the viewer be?

Comment: *Tantalum hafnium chloride?* Did you mean *Tantalum hafnium* **carbide**?

Comment: What Gert said. I'm all for awesome public science displays, but this sounds over the top to me. How do you propose to achieve 4000 K? Apart from the sheer danger, and the cost of the materials, that's going to cost a lot to supply the necessary energy.

Comment: $4000\text{ K}$ is indeed ridiculous. That's kind of *thermite temperatures* and nothing that can be achieved with gas burners.

Comment: *will be heated to 4000° kelvin*  What on Earth for ?   What's your goal in doing that ?

Comment: @StephenG - This is the ideal place to say "For Art!" Why else?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "Sun" is a black body, one can use the Stefan-Boltzmann equation to calculate the power radiated by the ball. The power per unit surface is $\sigma T^4$ with $\sigma$ about $5.7 \times 10^{-8} W/m^2/K^4$. I'm getting about 16.5 MW of power radiated at 4000K. Temperature to the fourth power is really increasing fast when temperature increases. I would say that what you suggest is almost impossible to build.